# Can kexec be built to a standalone binary, to be used where kexec was not built into the kernel?

Tags: kernel, boot, kernel-modules

I have remote embedded Linux devices I am trying to update to a new kernel without having to physically access.  However, the command line options they boot with make one of the MTDs read only - I cannot modify the kernel, and U-Boot is only accessible over a physical, serial connection.

kexec support was not installed.

I am trying to build kexec myself, but not having any success.  I have built the kexec from kexec-tools, but when I attempt to load a kernel, I get:

```
kexec_load failed: Function not implemented
```

Is there any way I can salvage this situation?  Can kexec be made as a single binary executable?  I have seen on forums where people have suggested they were using it this way, but I cannot seem to build it as such.

**Edit:**  If making kexec work is not an option, is there any way I can get access to MTD0?  I don't have access to one of the devices this second, but there's something like /proc/something/devices/virtual/mtd0/ro, which is 1, and if I chmod 777 it I can echo 0 > to it without any errors, but it doesn't stick.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe kexec can be built as a module, then loaded into the running kernel? At least if modules are enabled.

Comment: @derobert - that was a thought.  I've toyed with it, but no success thus far, and I'm not even entirely sure I'm doing it right - I've never made a module other than a little hello world before.

Comment: Build it as a module, as in pick 'M' instead of 'N' to the kexec option in the kernel config, then build the kernel (or at least the modules). If done with the same build environment & kernel sources as the running kernel, that should leave you with a `kexec.ko` ready for `insmod` on the target system. Then kexec-tools will work like normal. (I'd post as an answer, but I'm not sure if kexec can be built as a module).

Comment: @derobert - The hooks do appear to be there in the kexec.c source, but menuconfig only gives you =y or =n as options.  I'm currently trying to pull out the relevant pieces and hammer it into a module by hand.

Comment: Just for kicks check if maybe you could modify the mtd partition containing the U-boot env vars, but I'm sure that's read only too, right?

Answer (score 2):

`kexec` is a mechanism by which the *running kernel* replaces itself by another one. An external program doing so would have to have an *extremely* intimate knowledge of the kernel(s) involved, and kernel-level access to everything on the machine too. Perhaps doable, but I think nobody is crazy enough to try.

Comment: That complex? I thought `kexec` did about the same as Grub: Load the kernel image and the initrd into memory, tell them where and start it. What should it do more? I quote from the man page: "The primary difference between a standard system boot and a kexec boot is that the hardware initialization normally performed by the BIOS or firmware (depending on architecture) is not performed during a kexec boot."

Comment: @HaukeLaging - That was my thought.  I've seen on a few forums where people have allegedly flashed new Android kernels using kexec binaries, but I can't find any instruction as to how.